# Risk probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In Risk, if a player attacks another player they can roll up to 3 dice. The defending player can choose to roll either 1 or 2 dice in defence. Let's say that the attackers three dice are labelled $B_1$, $B_2$, and $B_3$, and the defenders two dice are labelled $C_1$ and $C_2$. They are listed such that $B_{(1)}$≤ $B_{(2)}$≤ $B_{(3)}$ where  $B_{(3)}$ denotes the highest number of eyes of the three dices of the attacker, and that $C_{(1)}$≤ $C_{(2)}$ where $C_{(2)}$ denotes the highest number of eyes of the two dices of the defender.

I want to find the probability and distribution function for $C_{(2)}$. My TA wrote on the blackboard that we could use the fact that the event $\{C_{2}\leq K\}$ for $k \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ fulfills that: $ \{C_{(2)}≤k\} =  \{C_1≤k\} ∩ \{C_2≤k\}$

But I just can't see what he means. I know that the the probability for a single dice roll is:

$$P(j=k)=\frac{1}{6}\quad \quad ∀k∈ \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} $$

Comment: it should be: 
$$P\left(j=k\right)=\frac{\left(2k-1\right)}{36}=k^{2}-\left(k-1\right)^{2}$$

Comment: You divide with 36, because that's $6^{2}$ right? But where do you get 2k-1 from?

Comment: there are $k^2$ ways to roll two numbers k or below and there are $(k-1)^2$ ways to roll two numbers k-1 or below, I am just subtracting the probabilites from each other to get the probability to roll at least one k

Comment: Thank you, I see. Shouldn't the last term also be divided with 36? So that all of the probabilities add up to 1?

Comment: yes, I may or may not have forgot that

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help though! I am a complete beginner in probability and find it very intriguing! It is almost magical how it all adds up to 1

Comment: Would it be correct to say that (=)= \frac{^2−(−1)^2}{6^2} is the probability function for C_{(2)}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $C_{(2)}$ is the higher value of the two dice, that means that: if $C_{(2)}$=k then $C_{(1)}\le{k}$. So both dice rolled numbers that are k or less.

The number of outcomes, where both values are k or less are: $k^2$.

From these outcomes, we need to remove the ones where neither $C_{(1)}$=k nor $C_{(2)}$=k. These are they ones that both dice have a value less than k (ie. k-1 or below). The number of such outcomes are: $(k-1)^2$.

So the number of outcomes we are left with are $k^2 - (k-1)^2$. Divide this with the total number of outcomes, to get the requested probability:

$$
P=\frac{k^2 - (k-1)^2}{36}
$$

Comment: , we need to remove the ones where neither  (1) =k nor (2) =k. These are they ones that both dice have a value less than k (ie. k-1 or below). How is this possible?  One of them must equal k

Comment: Yes exactly, one of them must equal k. This is why we are removing all the outcomes where both dice have value less than k (because they don't fulfil the statement: "one of them must equal k").